# For an Arcane Bloodline Sorcerer, does casting a spell with your bonded item cost a spell slot?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer, spellcasting, spell-slots, bloodline

I'm helping a friend build their first Sorcerer in *Pathfinder*.  We have decided to take the Arcane Bloodline.   While I am not used to playing a magic user, I am GM every other weekend with my group.  I have always been a little shaky on the way some of the magic works.

The Arcane Bloodline gets an Arcane Bond like a Wizard does.  This allows a wizard to cast a spell from his spell book without having to prepare it in one of his spell slots ahead of time.  The sorcerer is a spontaneous caster. 
The Sorcerer's bloodline Arcane Bond says:

> Once per day, *your bonded item* allows you to cast any one of your
>   spells known.

Then what is the point of that feature, and how does it work?  My player has a choice between using a familiar or a bonded item.

**Can the sorcerer cast a spell they know without using a spell slot?**  They already cast any spell that they know at will, as long as they have the slot to use it.  What's the benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't such a great pick for a sorcerer, a familiar will be nicer for them in the long run generally.

The sorcerer has limited spells per day and per level - so a bonded item will give the sorcerer a free extra spell of any level that they can cast.

For example - if they've used up all their level 3 spells and really want to cast a fireball? Then they can by using the bonded item.

Note the title of this question was "does casting a spell with your familiar cost a spell slot? If so, whats the point?"
The choice for the arcane bond is a familiar OR a bonded item, not both. The familiar will not let you cast a bonus spell, but they may be able to use wands, scout, dance amusingly, get you into trouble....

Comment: I see, so they would be able to cast an additional spell they know without the use of another a spell slot if they had taken a bonded item rather than a familiar? That is if I am understanding you correctly?

Comment: Yes. This is much more useful for wizards as it allows they to cast any spell they know without preparation, which is quite useful (in my experience).

Comment: Ok. So a bonded items spell can be cast without the use of an additional spell slot by the caster, that is the big answer I really needed. Thank you very much. The player was honestly just really excited to have a magical fox companion so im sure they will hold onto it even with the lack of this ability. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I edited the question to try and incorporate the discussion you two are having in comments.  @ViConstantine Please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: This answer could be improved by front-loading the fact that the Bonded Item is, indeed, a bonus spell slot. You can include your Familiar pitch as a postscript